# Python For Loop list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am looking for a possible equivalent of the following loop in python list comprehension.

```
    for foo in foos:
        if foo.text == expected_text
            return foo
    return []
```

Something like this.

```
found_foo = [foo for foo in foos if foo.text == expected_text]
```

If this possible using list comprehension?

Comment: You return either a single `foo` or an empty list? This is not usually a good design

Comment: I am confused how to skip / terminate the loop when the foo_found is mathced.

Comment: Yeah `found_foo` is actually a list with length == 1 and when the match is not found `[]` with length is returned

Answer (score 5):

You can use [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
return next((foo for foo in foos if foo.text == expected_text), None)
```

Next will return the first yielded item that meet the condition.

In case of no matched item, `next` will return  the default value `None`.

Comment: yes. It avoids running along the whole iterable if the element is found.